# when checkbox is checked, wrong value is submitted for the property

Tags: jqgrid

In the jqgrid, the column is defined as following:

```
  {name:'production', index:'production', width:60, align:'center', formatter:'checkbox',editable:true,edittype:'checkbox',editoptions:{value:"true:false"},formoptions:{ rowpos:10,elmprefix:"&nbsp;" }},
```

Generated html for the edit form is the following:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="true:false" offval="false" id="production" role="checkbox" class="FormElement">
```

So when the checkbox is unchecked, the correct value 'false' is submitted, but when the checkbox is checked, 'true:false' is submitted, which is obviously wrong. I would want 'true' to be submitted. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try removing editoptions like that :

```
{name:'production', index:'production', width:60, align:'center', formatter:'checkbox',editable:true,edittype:'checkbox',formoptions:{ rowpos:10,elmprefix:"&nbsp;" }},
```

from jqgrid wiki :

> If in editoptions, the value property
>   is not set, jqGrid searches for the
>   following values
>   (false|0|no|off|undefined) in order to
>   construct the checkbox.

so it should work for true:false out of the box .

Make also sure that in your data you have  production as true or false value

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the values should be True/False not Yes/No. add this attribute in the column:

```
editoptions: { value: "True:False" }
```