# jqgrid submitted wrong value for checkbox

Tags: jqgrid, checkbox

I have found similar question ([when checkbox is checked, wrong value is submitted for the property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5735384/when-checkbox-is-checked-wrong-value-is-submitted-for-the-property)), but it did't solve my problem.

I use jgrid for data presenting and editing. Everything works great if I use only text fields, but when i started to use checkboxes it fails. I have really simply code with default values:

```
colModel:[  {name:'robotsi',index:'robotsi', width:90, align:"right",sortable:false,editable:true,edittype:'checkbox'}  ]
```

In HTML it looks preatty well:

```
<input id="robotsi" class="FormElement" type="checkbox" value="on" offval="off" name="robotsi" role="checkbox">
```

But when I click 'submit' I got:

```
[robotsi] => off
```

even if I check it... when I added:

```
editoptions: { value:"Yes:No" }
```

it worked the same, only value I got was 0. I have noone JavaScript error at all.

Please help me to see what kind of mistake I do.

Comment: What version of jQuery do you have?

Comment: I had newest jQuery. I just solve it using select instead of checkbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not very elegant but I have fixed the problem by adding this code:

```
onInitializeForm: function(formId) {
    $(".FormGrid input[type='checkbox']").bind("load click", function() {
        $(this).attr("value", $(this).is(":checked"));
    });
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
colModel:[  {name:'robotsi',index:'robotsi', width:90, align:"right",sortable:false,editable:true,edittype:'checkbox' formatter:'checkbox'}  ]
```